# Generate code for dialog

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I have a main window, but wanted to create my own dialog. I have added a new form via

```
Solution Explorer -> Form Files -> New -> Qt Dialog Form.
```

Is there a way to generate source files for this dialog?

I think I have found the solution. Indeed there is a generated file, but the class does not subclass qdialog, instead I passed it as a parameter. I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

```
QDialog d;
Ui_Dialog dialog;
dialog.setupUi(&d);
d.exec();
```

Comment: You wanted to have a custom dialog like this? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Qt plug-in, then building the solution will run `uic` on the `.ui` file and generate the sources.

You should not `exec()` the dialog, since that's a blocking function that re-enters the event loop. You should simply `show()` it. If you want to get "results" from the dialog (acceptance/cancellation), you should connect to the signals that `QDialog` emits, like `accepted()`.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: You mean, how do you use it?

Comment: sorry, I meant show. I recall there should be an exec function, but the generated cpp has class that does not subclass anything.

Comment: I think I got it, although I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. I have added the code to my question.